# How to access rails server in a remote VM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, remote-access, openstack

I set up a Virtual Machine (VM) on OpenStack remotely. The VM is running Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 7.

I ssh into the above VM using `ssh vm-url`, and then I setup a rails server during that ssh session and get it running using `rails server -b vm-url`

Now, I try to access the rails website above from my local Chrome browser by typing the URL `vm-url:3000` into Chrome's address bar (the Omnibox), but I get:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> 10.150.8.101 took too long to respond.

Why Can't I access the rails website, what have I done wrong?

Please correct me if any terminologies I used are incorrect.

Thank you.

Comment: Please add more details; "VM" is a generic term. Do you mean a VMWare VM? Virtualbox? Vagrant? AWS? And your "Google address bar" means your "Chromium web browser address bar"...

Comment: I use OpenStack and create RHEL VM on it. I use Google Chrome and I entered `vm-url:3000` into its omnibox

Comment: I have updated my questions to include more details.

Comment: Two things to check, the ip attached to the VM is public and accessible, http port is enabled to be accessed from outside.

Comment: Hi @bijendra , your point is the answer. I did these: Go to Access & Security > Create Security Group with (Name: web-server-dev) and (Port: 3000). Then I did: Go back to Instances > the instance we are using > drop down menu > Edit Security Groups: Add the web-server-dev group

Comment: If you write an answer I will accept

Comment: Cool, done with answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to check,

- The ip attached to the VM is public and accessible
- Http port is enabled to be accessed from outside

The port accessed is handled in security groups which is generally configured while creating the instance. Either add new security group with enough privileges or update the same with new added ports.